# Max sockets for HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sockets

I am building a php page that generates html5 audio elements from an rss feed.

```
<? foreach($tracks as $track){ ?>

    <audio controls >
        <source src="<?= $track['track_url'] ?>" type="audio/mpeg">  
        <source src="<?= $track['track_url'] ?>" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

<? } ?>
```

There are about 300 tracks in this case so I do not load them all at once (the above code is to illustrate the concept).

I load a few tracks initially, then load additional tracks as the user scrolls down.

You can check out the page here: http://canneconomy.com/podcast

The first few tracks load and play without issues. However, after 10 or so tracks are loaded, the user is no longer able to play the HTML5 audio elements. I believe this is because all of the sockets are occupied and no more can be used.

My proposed solution is to prevent the HTML5 audio elements from automatically reserving sockets as they are generated and manage this process manually. A socket would only be used when a user clicks the play button. Hitting another play button would free all sockets and occupy only one.

How would one go about managing socket connections manually? This is a PHP/jQuery app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired behaviour by adding `preload="none"` to each audio item which will prevent the initial download of the file until a user clicks on the play button.

Also from looking at your source your attempting to stop the player above when the user plays the next item `onplay="stop('trk2',300)"`, but that's a little optimistic that the user will traverse down the list instead of skipping a couple etc.

You can fix this issue by listening for a play event and then iterating over all players, then pausing them if it's not the target player.

A couple of very simple changes, for example:

```html
<audio controls preload="none" id="trk1" class="ht5player" style="width:100%">
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Paul_Final_-_12_15_17_1.55_PM.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/mpeg">  
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Paul_Final_-_12_15_17_1.55_PM.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls preload="none" id="trk2" class="ht5player" style="width:100%">
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Lori_Final_-_12_15_17_12.19_PM.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/mpeg">  
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Lori_Final_-_12_15_17_12.19_PM.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls preload="none" id="trk3" class="ht5player" style="width:100%">
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Sabrina_Final_-_12_13_17_5.03_PM_1.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/mpeg">  
    <source src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/canneconomy/Sabrina_Final_-_12_13_17_5.03_PM_1.mp3?dest-id=271554" type="audio/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
        var audio_elms = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
        for (var i = 0, length = audio_elms.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (audio_elms[i] != e.target) {
                audio_elms[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }, true);
</script>
```

^^^ run the snippet to see it in action.